# Subquery Sum returns duplicates

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I need to annotate the sum of “reserved_quantity” based on some filters.

With this code, I'm getting duplicates and, as a result, an inflated sum. I suspect it's due to filtering based on the reverse foreign key relationship listproduct__productionrequest__writingoffwarehouseproducts=None.

```py
    def annotate_total_reserved_by_opened_production_lists_quantity(self):
        return self.annotate(
            total_reserved_by_opened_production_lists_quantity=Coalesce(
                Subquery(
                    WarehouseProductReservationMapping.objects.filter(
                        Q(
                            warehouseproduct__current_technology_id=Case(
                                When(
                                    warehouseproduct__nomenclature__type__in=(
                                        product_structure_api.models.NomenclatureType.ASSEMBLY,
                                        product_structure_api.models.NomenclatureType.MANUFACTURED,
                                    ),
                                    then=OuterRef("current_technology_id"),
                                ),
                            )
                        )
                        | Q(
                            warehouseproduct__current_technology_id=None,
                            warehouseproduct__nomenclature__type=product_structure_api.models.NomenclatureType.PURCHASED,
                        ),
                        listproduct__for_list__is_completed=False,
                        warehouseproduct__nomenclature_id=OuterRef("nomenclature_id"),
                        listproduct__productionrequest__writtenoffwarehouseproducts=None,
                        warehouseproduct__quantity__gt=0,
                    )
                    .order_by()
                    .values("warehouseproduct__nomenclature_id")
                    .annotate(total_reserved_quantity=Sum("reserved_quantity"))
                    .values("total_reserved_quantity")[:1]
                ),
                0,
            )
        )
```

I've tried using Sum(field, Different=True) and also attempted to add .distinct() and .distinct("id") in different places in the subquery, but it didn't work. Currently, I've come up with the following code (which works correctly without duplicates), but it significantly impacts performance, running approximately 20 times slower. This is not acceptable, and I can't use it in production due to its speed.

```py
    def annotate_total_reserved_by_opened_production_lists_quantity(self):
        # Get reservation ids to filter only unique entries.
        reservation_ids = WarehouseProductReservationMapping.objects.filter(
            Q(
                warehouseproduct__current_technology_id=Case(
                    When(
                        warehouseproduct__nomenclature__type__in=(
                            product_structure_api.models.NomenclatureType.ASSEMBLY,
                            product_structure_api.models.NomenclatureType.MANUFACTURED,
                        ),
                        then=OuterRef(OuterRef("current_technology_id")),
                    ),
                )
            )
            | Q(
                warehouseproduct__current_technology_id=None,
                warehouseproduct__nomenclature__type=product_structure_api.models.NomenclatureType.PURCHASED,
            ),
            Q(
                listproduct__for_list__is_completed=False,
                listproduct__productionrequest__writtenoffwarehouseproducts=None,
            )
            | Q(for_order_product__isnull=False),
            warehouseproduct__nomenclature_id=OuterRef(OuterRef("nomenclature_id")),
            warehouseproduct__quantity__gt=0,
        ).values("id")
        subquery = Subquery(
            WarehouseProductReservationMapping.objects.filter(id__in=reservation_ids)
            .order_by()
            .values("warehouseproduct__nomenclature_id")
            .annotate(total_reserved_quantity=Sum("reserved_quantity"))
            .values("total_reserved_quantity")[:1]
        )
        return self.annotate(
            total_reserved_by_opened_production_lists_quantity=Coalesce(
                subquery,
                0,
            )
        )
```

These are the models (with only used fields).

```py
class Product(models.Model):  # Base model to which I need to annotate sum.
    nomenclature = models.ForeignKey(
        product_structure_api.models.Nomenclature,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="warehouse_product",
    )
    current_technology = models.ForeignKey(
        product_structure_api.models.Technology,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, db_index=True)
```

```py
class NomenclatureType(TextChoices):
    PURCHASED = "0", "Purchased"
    ASSEMBLY = "1", "Assembly"
    MANUFACTURED = "2", "Manufactured"


class Nomenclature(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=NomenclatureType.choices,
        default=NomenclatureType.ASSEMBLY,
        help_text="""
        "0" = "Purchased"
        "1" = "Assembly"
        "2" = "Manufactured"
        """,
        db_index=True,
    )
```

```py
from mptt.models import MPTTModel


class ListProduct(MPTTModel):
    for_list = models.ForeignKey(
        List,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="forlistproduct_set",
    )
```

```py
class List(models.Model):
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

```py
class ProductionRequest(models.Model):
    list_product = models.ForeignKey(
        ListProduct,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

```py
class WrittenOffWarehouseProducts(models.Model):
    listproduct = models.ForeignKey(
        "ListProduct", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True
    )
    productionrequest = models.ForeignKey(
        "ProductionRequest", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    warehouseproduct = models.ForeignKey(
        "Product",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

```py
class WarehouseProductReservationMapping(models.Model):
    warehouseproduct = models.ForeignKey(
        "Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    reserved_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1, db_index=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
    )
```

I would appreciate any help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the related models as well as *what* you want to do, and not only *how* you are trying to do that?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I shared my models with used fields. Tell me if I forgot something, please.